# Impossible filter design on bad amplifier

Tags: filter, passive-filter, power-amplifier

I just recently created [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKZB.png) audio amplifier. I built it with real components and it works great. I built it without the "EQ" parts though, since I had not created them yet, so I don't know if they actually work, but they do work completely as I expect on Falstad Simulator.

Now I decided to create another audio amplifier, which so far looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpbF2q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It works as I expect on Falstad Simulator.
The problem is, I seem to be unable to implement a filter on the audio input. I have tried moving the audio input around, splitting the filter into multiple blocks at different locations, but nothing works. Somehow I seem to only be able to either do a high pass, or a low pass, but not both at the same time with just passive components. I'm suspecting it has something to do with Q1 not being where the audio input signal wants to flow to, but I still couldn't do anything about it.

The filter I'm trying to make is a band reject that diminishes 1.1kHz to 0.35 its level with a certain valley width. I implemented it successfully (at least with the results from the simulator) on [my previous audio amplifier circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGKZB.png).
The intended filter looks like this:

[image: Filter]

What could I do?
Is my circuit just bad?

Here are some of my many attempts at the filter:
[Attempt A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuD2k.png)
[Attempt B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUgRs.png)
[Attempt C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8JtD.png)

By the way, I'm creating these circuits myself. I think people in the comments seem to think I'm getting them from somewhere. I am totally against copying and executing other's ideas and fully trusting they will work for you even though you have no idea what you're doing or don't understand how those ideas are supposed to work. I'm here trying to learn.

Comment: can you show us how your filter implementation look like, as a schematic? I'll venture a guess: you concatenated a filter with a (inherently) high output impedance directly to another filter that assumes zero source impedance.

Comment: Also, um, an audio amplifier with 1960's Darlingtons (really? the TIP120 in 2021?) without negative feedback just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Also, um, why the 56 V supply? That seems waaay overkill lest you want to put >100W through your 24 Ω speaker? Is that the goal here? In that case, no, a Darlington like that becomes a huge liability in terms of waste heat, and is not appropriate, unless you really like large heat sinks.

Comment: I have great doubts about your design. Besides what @MarcusMüller points out, why are you feeding your input like that? That Q1 has its base straight to the 56 V through the input (which isn't high impedance, is it?). Then R3 is 27 Ohms? Not lastly, just because some schematic *simulates* in some simulator, it doesn't mean it will *work* in real life. And Falstadt is not what engineers all around the world use in their designs. It's a simple, good enough simulator for basic usage, with idealized components.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, the R2 location is a mistake, thank you! I have now fixed it. Do you mean to show my attempts at my filter on the current circuit? I'll add the examples as soon as I can. About the negative feedback on the transistors, I think I understand what you mean, though I'm not how I would implement that. Yes, my supply is 56V: according to the simulator the load only receives up to 43V, and my speaker is capable of 100W, I had thought about Pd on R4 and R8 but had not about the Pd on the transistors yet... gotta check that.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yes, I know about simulators just being tools and the real world being completely different, thank you. Could you elaborate more about the problems you found on my circuit?

Comment: @ImprovisedTheme see, if your supply is 56 V, and your speaker only sees 43 V, then the missing 13 V get converted to heat in your power transistors. Assuming 2 A RMS current through your speaker (amounting to 96 W power) that means 26 W in waste heat.

Comment: @ImprovisedTheme well, you won't build a well-sounding amplifier without negative feedback: A transistor, and even more so a Darlington transistor pair, is a non-linear thing, and will introduce harmonics into your audio unless compensated, or only operated over a narrow operational range. The schematic you've linked to *has* negative feedback for exactly that reason. Honestly, I'd probably recommend learning about negative feedback amplifiers!

Comment: @ImprovisedTheme Do you need this schematic in particular, or do you need an amplifier that can deliver 100 W? If the latter, may I suggest some tried and tested designs? It looks like you're comfortable with large distortions, so using such a design has the added benefit that it's safer to work with a 56 V supply. If the former, I can only wish you good luck, but that's not something I'd recommend.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I checked the Pd on the transistors and they indeed stay at 0W during no input, and swing only up to 21W at max level, and I'm completely OK with that. On my previous circuit the transistors deal with a Pd of 60W so I definitely gave them big heat sinks. I understand about the negative feedback, I'm working on it now, thank you!

Comment: that's just a terrible thing to be content with! Being brutally honest here, 100 W calls for something that's basically class-D or hybrid-

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen The only reason I'm making this is because I'm learning about electronics. I do not need nor want a 100W amplifier, I'm making one because I just so happen to have a 24Ohm speaker and a 56V supply. I just started learning about electronics since less than three months ago, and I've been reading as many schematics as I can, and I'll continue to do so. I'm just trying to learn. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I actually want to make a class-D one right after this one. The inductors are what are still scaring me away from class-D since I still don't understand inductors very well yet. I read that I could use inductors as current sources to double the voltage on the amplifiers with transistors, but I have not yet been able to get good results on the simulator.

Comment: @ImprovisedTheme cool! Yeah, then learning about the idea behind negative feedback is a great idea / learning experience. You might want to learn about common opamp circuits on the way, since that makes designing a driver for your Darlington output stages way easier to understand (and in fact, the schematic you've linked to does exactly that – use NE5532 opamps in a negative feedback loop to make the output of your Darlington stage look exactly as it should).

Comment: @ImprovisedTheme I'd recommend ignoring the details about the inductors in a class D amplifier then, on a first approach. Think of them as filtering out the high-frequency noise the class D amplification causes (which isn't actually noise, but... later.). Understanding class D is quite a cool thing to do, because it teaches one a lot about the mathematical nature of the signals underneath all this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the suggestions. I'm definitely going to research all about them. I wanted to make this circuit work without any op-amps, I hope manage to do it. I think I understand class-D already, it's just that inductors keep giving me headaches in general. I'm experienced in signal processing software wise so I thought audio in hardware would be a piece of cake. It is not. Phase shift of current is like a whole new dimension to me.

Comment: yeah, if you come from a DSP side (much like me), then class-D feels "natural" (in fact, it feels way more natural than class B to me)

Comment: There is no base biassing on the output stage ... expect all kinds of troubles including crossover distortion, limited headroom and random DC across the speaker.